# KISS: StringName to class

Tags: .net, vb.net, linq, oop, class

I have two classes `xCustomer` and `xProduct`

```
   Case Tables.xCustomer
     Dim Count As Integer = (From t In New XPQuery(Of xCustomer)(DefaultSession) Select t.CustomerID).Count
     Return Count + 1
   Case Tables.xProduct
     Dim Count As Integer = (From t In New XPQuery(Of xProduct)(DefaultSession) Select t.ProductID).Count
     Return Count + 1
```

How can i simplify the above statements, lets say by using a string to class conversion?

For example i would like to use something like

Dim Test as object

Test = ReturnClassOfString("xCustomer")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps using reflection? This should help you get started with reflection in general:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/cc163750.aspx

This should help you with your actual question: http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/VB.Net:_Create_an_instance_of_class_from_a_string_using_reflection

Comment: glad to see my wiki article comes in handy ;-)